# Error while generate entityframe work model for firebird database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird, firebird-2.0

I installed firebird provider in visual studio 2017 i can see tables in server explorer when i try to generate model codefirst from database i found the provider and test the connection string well 
when i choose the datatable and press next to start generate model that error appear 
[image]

the output is

> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException: Dynamic SQL Error
>   SQL error code = -104
>   Token unknown - line 50, column 14
>   POSITION ---> FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: Dynamic SQL Error
>   SQL error code = -104
>   Token unknown - line 50, column 14
>   POSITION
>      at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ProcessResponse(IResponse response)
>      at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadResponse()
>      at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadGenericResponse()
>      at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsStatement.Prepare(String commandText)
>      at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.Prepare(Boolean returnsSet)
>      at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean returnsSet)
>      at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.Execute(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadDataTable[T](String sql, Func`2 orderByFunc, DataTable table, EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes queryTypes, IEnumerable`1 filters, String[] filterAliases)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadTableDetails(IEnumerable`1 filters)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadStoreSchemaDetails(IList`1 filters)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GetStoreSchemaDetails(StoreSchemaConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.CreateStoreModel()
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GenerateModel(List`1 errors)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModels(String storeModelNamespace, ModelBuilderSettings settings, List`1 errors)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModel(ModelBuilderSettings settings, IVsUtils vsUtils, ModelBuilderEngineHostContext hostContext)'.
>   Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:00.4765840.
>   Generating the model took 00:00:27.8739728.

my connection string is `data source=192.168.1.32;initial catalog=C:\blabla\blabla.FDB;user id=blaUser;dialect=3`

my configuration 
  FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 6.0.0
  EntityFramework.Firebird 6.0.0
  EntityFramework 6.2.0
  Firebird-2.0.0.12748-0-Win32   // i know it's old version but unfortunately i can't change it cause i'm not the owner of database

Comment: As far as I'm aware, recent versions of Firebird .net provider only support Firebird versions that are currently supported by the Firebird project, that is Firebird 2.5.x and 3.0.x. Seriously, start updating. For one, 2.0.x (and 2.1.x) contains known security issues (and 2.0.0 isn't even the last version of 2.0.x). So continuing to use Firebird 2.0.x is a security liability.

Comment: The problem is I can not touch the database or database server I'm not the owner of that and I need to provide a web app to some of the data base just for read

Comment: But you can make your client aware of the problems and risks involved by running ancient Firebird versions, Firebird 2.0.0 is 12 years old, the last 2.0.x was released 6 years ago, it has known security bugs. In any case have you considered trying with older versions of the Firebird .NET provider?

Comment: I tottaly agree with you ,and I told him but this data base is connected to old services that run and receive data from other services located in hundred deferent locations.  ,,, We afraid that if we update data base and FB server the old services will not compatible with it and we don not have source code ,, that will be temporarily solution and later the system will completely updated. Thank you